# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'CSSTransitionGroup' of undefined, react addons

Tags: reactjs, add-on

I need to use react addons, ReactCSSTransitionGroup, but still I have error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'CSSTransitionGroup' of undefined.

I have react, react-dom and ReactCSSTransitionGroup v: 15.4.2, so shouldn't have problem with it. I have installed react-addons-css-transition-group via mpn.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';
const ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;
```

I add to webpack configuration

```
externals: {
  'react/addons': true,
  'react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment': true,
  'react/lib/ReactContext': true
  }
```

but it didn't help

I use it in index.js (in Alert folder):

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import BasicAlert from './basicAlert';

import {
    alertsWrapper,
    enter,
    enterActive,
    leave,
    leaveActive,
} from './alertsHandler.scss';

import CSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';
//const ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;

const AlertsHandler = ({ closeTime, alerts = [] }) => (
    <div className={alertsWrapper}>
        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
            transitionName={{
                enter,
                enterActive,
                leave,
                leaveActive,
            }}
            transitionEnterTimeout={500}
            transitionLeaveTimeout={500}
        >
            {alerts.map(item => (
                <BasicAlert
                    closeTime={closeTime}
                    {...item}
                    key={`alert${item.id}`}
                />
                ))}
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    </div>
);


AlertsHandler.propTypes = {
    closeTime: PropTypes.number,
    alerts: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
       id: PropTypes.string,
        type: PropTypes.string,
        alertContent: PropTypes.node,
        repeated: PropTypes.number,
    })),
};

export default AlertsHandler;
```

and import in App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Alert from '../components/Alerts';

var example = 'whatever';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <div>
        <Alert closeTime={3000} alerts={example} />
      </div>);
  }
}
```

I try to import:  import React, { PropTypes } from 'react/addons'; and import { __Addons as addons, PropTypes } from 'react' but it give me error canno't read property addons of undefine. I even tryed to import directly from node_modules or use depreciate module react-addons.

I'm not sure, but I think there is problem with import react-with-addons, but I can't find properly way to do it.

If I gave to less information, please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReactCSSTransitionGroup` is not a export from the main `React` package.

Just remove the third line `const ReactCSSTransitionGroup = ...`.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';
```

This should work

**Update 1**:
Subsequent error being thrown can be resolved like so

In index.js (in Alert folder):

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
...
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';
//const ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;

const AlertsHandler = ({ closeTime, alerts = [] }) => (
    <div className={alertsWrapper}>
        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
            ...
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    </div>
);
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately it give me next error: Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `App`.

Comment: Not related to this question though, this is not a consultation service for you to resolve series of doubts. This question got answered.

Comment: Kept only relevant stuff in the answer, so that you could pinpoint where the mistake was

Comment: No Problem. Try to debug more from your side. Give your best shot before asking it here.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I was using a `className` prop on my CSSTransition component. It should be `classNames`. Spent hours figuring that out... just posting in case it helps somebody.

Comment: wow, this was it for me exactly!!! Thank you for leaving this answer :)!

Comment: Saved me an hour! Thank you.

Comment: I'd removed the 'S' thinking it was an error.. Thanks a mil, saved me SO much pain!